# Releasing underlying Stream returned by Application.GetResourceStream on WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

When accessing a resource using `Application.GetResourceStream` it returns an instance of the class `StreamResourceInfo`, this class does not implement IDisposable.

Should I close\dispose the underlying stream exposed by `StreamResourceInfo` when I've finished processing the stream on a WP7 device - I don't want to know about `Using` or the Dispose pattern.

An example would be using the method to access a ZIP file which is contained with the ZAP package and once I have unzipped the file I don't need the `Stream` instance anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code example provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resources.streamresourceinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) does not make use of `using`, `Close()` or `Dispose()`.

Since the documentation for `StreamResourceInfo` doesn't mention `Close()` or `Dispose()` (and `StreamResourceInfo` does not actually inherit from `Stream` or anything else that might implement these methods), I think it's safe to just let the object go out of scope and garbage collect naturally.

I suspect that the `StreamResourceInfo` class has a finalizer that calls `Dispose()` on the underlying `Stream` object during garbage collection, but I don't have a copy of Reflector available to me at the moment to verify that.  The `IDisposable` pattern is quite robust in that regard.

However, if you still feel uncomfortable with that level of uncertainty, you can always call `Close()` on the `Stream` object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Windows 7 phone specifically, but the standard practice is to dispose the object and it does automatically close the stream if it is opened. Disposing should be the final operation on an object whereas close indicates possibility of reopening. So you should go for dispose in my opinion.

Comment: thanks I understand the dispose pattern, the problem is the StreamResourceInfo  does not have a dispose method it's self, but the contained Stream does.

Comment: Then you have no option but to call close. The stream should ideally be implemented in such a way that it should call dispose of underlying stream once it is closed in this case. are you able to access underlying stream anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

`Using` automatically calls the dispose method once the end of the `using` scope is reached. So, you could do something like this. Once the end of the scope is reached, your stream will be removed.

```
 using (var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("myResource.zip", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
 {
       //stream code
 }
```

EDIT - Moving responses from comments to here:
The StreamResourceInfo isn't responsible for the closing/disposing of the Stream. Unless you pass that Stream to something else (e.g. a StreamReader), then it's your job to close the stream. [Found a link that may be of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143899/dispose-streamresourceinfo-stream) which pretty much goes along with that.

Comment: @AwkwardCoder - I saw it, but I don't see what the problem is. `StreamResourceInfo` is not reponsible for the stream - you are. Therefore, the onus is on you to close/dispose the stream. `Using`, or manually calling `Dispose` on the stream is the way to do that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "Using automatically calls the dispose method once the end of the using scope is reached. " - ever thought i might know this... I am asking about a specific class in the framework return by a call to Application.GetResourceStream.

Comment: @AwkwardCoder: Downvoted for adding context? Lets not forget, other people read this post as well who may not know this. I'd like this to think this is a professional forum, so it's a shame you have to resort to petty actions and sarcasm. I simply explained that the StreamResourceInfo isn't responsible for the closing/disposing of the Stream. Unless you pass that Stream to something else (e.g. a StreamReader), then it's your job to close the stream.

Comment: Have you read the guidelines for implementing a class which internally creates and exposes a property which needs disposing?

Comment: I suggest you read the law of demeter and the principles of object orientation as well.

Comment: @AwkwardCoder - Can't say I have. Why do you ask?