# Most appropriate usage of stream returned by App.GetResourceStream

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, stream, idisposable

My question has already kind of been asked at [Releasing underlying Stream returned by Application.GetResourceStream on WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200732/releasing-underlying-stream-returned-by-application-getresourcestream-on-wp7), but I have a couple variations on the question:

1. This is for a desktop WPF application, not WP7 if it makes any difference.
2. I have to decide whether to use a `using` block on a stream reader built on top of the stream.

Here's some code:

```
System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo ri = 
   App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Idioms.txt", UriKind.Relative));
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ri.Stream))
{
   idioms = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(lineSeps, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Now StreamReader's close method (which I assume is the method that implements `IDisposable.Dispose`) indicates that it also closes the underlying stream (which I assume is also implementing `IDisposable.Dispose`).

So is this closing or disposing of the `IO.Stream` object provided by `GetResourceStream`'s `Stream` property:

1. Expected
2. Acceptable, or
3. Incorrect

(Should I use or avoid `using` on the reader built on top of the stream?)

Answer (score 1):

`StreamReader`'s ctor has an overload that lets you tell it to keep the stream from being closed.

Also, you have it slightly backwards (unless I misunderstood).  It's the `Dispose` method that calls `Close`, not the other way around.

Comment: There is no accessible Dispose method on StreamReader so I assumed that the Close method is the one implementing Dispose on IDisposable. I suppose the other possibility is that it's private and only accessible when the object is cast to IDisposable. If the later is the case then I guess it would make sense for Dispose to call Close. But I see no reason Close and Dispose couldn't be doing the same thing. Can you continue to use a reader after it is closed, so long as it's not disposed?

Comment: Also, my question remains, should I be taking advantage of the option to leave the stream open if the stream was on an object returned by GetResourceStream? I am using the code as shown in my question and not getting any errors. Can I then safely assume that I don't need to suppress the closing of the stream?